# media query - can I use seperate, independant stylesheet?

Tags: html, mobile, css, media-queries

I was only introduced to media queries yesterday while researching building my mobile optimized pages. I have found that contrary to my initial interpretation a media query directs to a stylesheet that is used in addition to and overrides the existing stylesheet.

Is that right? Is there a way to tell the visitors browser to ignore the original stylesheet and just use the one for mobile?

Here is existing code:

```
<link href="styles_mobile.css" media="screen and (max-device-width: 480px)" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

<link type="text/css" href="styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

Answer (score 3):

It's perfectly acceptable to do so.